# What Would Be The Most Common Food Staples For A Tilted Earth

Tags: civilization, food, agriculture

On this planet, which resembles Earth but tilted so that Africa is now the north pole and the middle of the Pacific is the South pole (the geography are quite similar to the world of Jaredia over on [Planetcopia](http://www.worlddreambank.org/J/JAREDIA.HTM)) What would be the most common staples in a long stretch of rain forested and slightly mountainous land no more than 30 degrees north or south from the equator?
The foods can come from S. America, Central America, Southern North America, Asia, Indonesia, Australia as well as any other foodstuffs that could grow in the climates provided. The foods do not have to be in raw form, they can be certain kinds of dishes as well, as long as the arnt a very specific aspect of a real world culture.

Comment: My vote would be `triceratops`.  Although `humans` comes a close 2nd.  I think  your question is too broad.  What ever grows between 30N and 30S now will grow between 30N and 30S then

Comment: Aubergines (eggplants), beans, cantaloupes, cassava, cocoa, coconuts, coffee, cucumbers, dates, figs, maize (corn), mangoes, manioc, millet, onions, oranges, peanuts, pineapples, plantains (the banana kind), rice, sorghum, soy beans, sugar cane, sweet potatoes, teff, tomatoes, watermelons, wheat, yams... And of course cattle, chickens, pigs and goats.